# MDX CalculatedMember Issue 20120713

Tags: ssas, mdx, hierarchy, dimension

I'm having an issue with the following calculated member,

```
WITH MEMBER NewSeedGBP AS
IIF([Dim Player].[FirstTransaction].Value =[Dim Date].[CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember, 

   ([Dim Player].[FirstTransaction].[Date], [Measures].[Amount GBP - Seed])

   , IIF([Dim Player].[FirstDeposit].Value = [Dim Date].[CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember, 

        ([Dim Player].[FirstDeposit].[Date], [Measures].[Amount GBP - Seed])

        ,NULL))

SELECT {NewSeedGBP} ON COLUMNS,
{[Dim Date].[CalendarYearMonth].[Date]} ON ROWS
FROM Finance
```

I'd like this to return measure `Amount GBP - Seed` where the FirstTransaction Value equals the CalendarYearMonth OR FirstDeposit Value equals CalendarYearMonth - they are both date values YYYY-MM

The IIF validation works fine , although in the THEN clause I need the `[Dim Player].[FirstTransaction].[Date]` value to reference the `[Dim Date].[CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember` from the IIF statement, unfortunately due to them being in different hierarchies there is no .CurrentMember for `[Dim Player].[FirstDeposit].[Date]` in the THEN clause, I've tested that it works if I hard code a date as below

```
([Dim Player].[FirstTransaction].[2012-07], [Measures].[Amount GBP - Seed])
```

I need to bring back the `[Measures].[Amount GBP - Seed]` for the hierarchy `[Dim Player].[FirstTransaction]` and not the `[Dim Date].[CalendarYearMonth]` hierarchy.

Though I'll need this calculated member to be able to join to `[Dim Date].[CalendarYearMonth]` hierarchy.